# If one of the multiple adds in a saveChangesAsync fails do the others get added?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this function in my application. If the insert of Phrase fails then can someone tell me if the Audit entry still gets added? If that's the case then is there a way that I can package these into a single transaction that could be rolled back.

Also if it fails can I catch this and then still have the procedure exit with an exception?

```
    [Route("Post")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Phrase phrase)
    {

        phrase.StatusId = (int)EStatus.Saved;
        UpdateHepburn(phrase);
        db.Phrases.Add(phrase);
        var audit = new Audit()
        {
            Entity = (int)EEntity.Phrase,
            Action = (int)EAudit.Insert,
            Note = phrase.English,
            UserId = userId,
            Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Id = phrase.PhraseId
        };
        db.Audits.Add(audit);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(phrase);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have this function in my application. If the insert of Phrase fails
>   then can someone tell me if the Audit entry still gets added?

You have written your code in a correct way by calling `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` only one time after doing all your modifications on the `DbContext`.

The answer to your question is: No, the `Audit` will not be added if `Phrase` fails.
Because you are calling `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` after doing all your things with your entities, Entity Framework wil generate all the required SQL Queries and put them in a single SQL transaction which makes the whole queries as an atomic operation to your database. If one of the generated query e.g. `Audit`generated query failed then the transaction will be rolled back. So every modification that have been done to your database will be removed and so Entity Framework will let your database in a coherent state.

Comment: I want to have modifications independent - should I call db.SaveChangesAsync() after each of them?  If yes, should I use the same DbContext or better to create new for each modification?

Comment: Answer to myself-create new dbContext for each modification is preferred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188148/c-sharp-entity-framework-loop-through-records-savechanges-error