# c# entity framework loop through records savechanges() error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach, savechanges

I am doing an `C# Entity Framework` Application.

I am migrating data from a couple of tables from one database to another database. Those tables are called with the same name.

Here is my code

```html
string ConnexionOrigen = ReadConnectionBiz.GetOrigen();
string ConnexionDestino = ReadConnectionBiz.GetDestino();
using (var db = new MigrateModel(ConnexionOrigen))
{
  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
  List<Promocion> promo = await (from p in db.Promocions
                               .Include(a =>a.PromocionAddresIds)
                         where (p.CAM_ID == 107936 || p.CAM_ID == 107937)
                        select p)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToListAsync();

  var dbDestino = new MigrateModel(ConnexionDestino);
  foreach (Promocion pp in promo)
  {
    try
    {
      dbDestino.Promocions.Add(pp);
      await dbDestino.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string err =  ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToString();
    }
 }
```

What it does here is:

I search in `Origen` Database from table `Promocions` and insert those records in Promotions table in Destino Database .

I include a child table called `PromocionAddresIds` that is migrated too.

Everythig works fine...

The table `PromocionAddresIds` has a constraint with a table that it is not been migrated.

When I insert the `Promotions` with `cam_id=107936` it thrown an exception of `contraint violation`... Witch is correct...

But when it read the next `Promotions` record with `Cam_id =107937`. That record has no record in table PromocionAddresIds, so it must be inserted, but it thrown the same error exception...

It appears that   `await dbDestino.SaveChangesAsync();` still have the all record or it persist somewhere...

I have tried adding

`dbDestino.Promocions.Remove(pp);` inside the `catch exception`, but it did not work.

I do not have any clue how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a single instance of data context for all iterations of the loop. All objects added to the context will live there until the context is disposed or cleared. The situation you observe is:

1. First entity is added
2. An attempt to save changes, but it is failed due to constraint violation
3. Second entity is added
4. Another attempt to save changes. And here both first and second entity will be attempted to be inserted, because they still belong to the data context.

Please also note that calling "save changes" after each entity usually is not efficient. It is better to insert a portion of entities (let's say 100) and persist it in one shot.

Comment: Note that If persist multiple records in one shot, they will be in one transaction, and, if one record failed, all records will be rejected. You may want or don’t want it.